# Can't convert list of lists to dictionary in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of lists:-

```py
[['Grade', 'V A'], ['Attendance', '16/26'], ['Session timings', '8:00 am - 8:40 am'], ['Grade', 'VII A'], ['Attendance', '24/31'], ['Session timings', '8:50 am - 9:30 am'], ['Grade', 'IX A'], ['Attendance', '20/26'], ['Session timings', '9:40 am - 10:20 am'], ['Grade', 'IX B'], ['Attendance', '21/25'], ['Session timings', '10:50 am - 11:30 am']]
```

And want to convert it to dictionary like this:-

```py
{{"Grade":"V A"}, {"Attendance": "16/26"} ... }
```

I tried using the zip method:-

```py
keys = []
values = []

for i in range(0, 12):
    string = str(message_list[i]).replace(',',';').replace('[','').replace(']','').replace("'","").split(";")
    keys.append(string[0])
    values.append(string[1])

new_dict = dict(zip(keys, values))
print(new_dict)
```

But it only prints:-

```py
{'Grade': ' IX B', 'Attendance': ' 21/25', 'Session timings': ' 10:50 am - 11:30 am'}
```

It prints only of Grade IX B, not other 3 grades. Please help me with the code...

But when I use `new_dict = list(zip(keys, values))` it prints the whole as a list of tuples:

```
[('Grade', ' V A'), ('Attendance', ' 16/26'), ('Session timings', ' 8:00 am - 8:40 am'), ('Grade', ' VII A'), ('Attendance', ' 24/31'), ('Session timings', ' 8:50 am - 9:30 am'), ('Grade', ' IX A'), ('Attendance', ' 20/26'), ('Session timings', ' 9:40 am - 10:20 am'), ('Grade', ' IX B'), ('Attendance', ' 21/25'), ('Session timings', ' 10:50 am - 11:30 am')]
```

Then why doesn't it print full dictionary? Please help me with the code.

Thank you!

Comment: You can't have the same key (e.g., 'Grade') repeated more than once in a dictionary... Keys must be unique

Comment: Please update your question with the new desired expected output

Comment: @Dr.StrangeCodes you can do nested dictionary

Comment: Yes, I have updated my expected result... 

Comment: You can't have `{{"Grade":"V A"}, {"Attendance": "16/26"} ... }`. This would be a set of dictionaries, but that's not possible because dictionaries are mutable and therefore not hashable in python.

Comment: How do you want the final csv file to be? If you tell us how the csv will look like, we can help you

Comment: The headings will be Grade Attandance and Session Timings
And other columns will have the info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is you are overwriting the already existing key and hence can see only the last entry of the `list` in your `dict`. Another approach can be to have a nested `dict` as below:

```
{
    'Grade-V A': {
        'Attendance': '16/26',
        'Session timings': '8:00 am - 8:40 am'
    },
    'Grade-VII A': {
        'Attendance': '24/31',
        'Session timings': '8:50 am - 9:30 am'
    },
    'Grade-IX A': {
        'Attendance': '20/26',
        'Session timings': '9:40 am - 10:20 am'
    },
    'Grade-IX B': {
        'Attendance': '21/25',
        'Session timings': '10:50 am - 11:30 am'
    }
}
```

with the below code:

```
data = [['Grade', 'V A'], ['Attendance', '16/26'], ['Session timings', '8:00 am - 8:40 am'], ['Grade', 'VII A'], ['Attendance', '24/31'], ['Session timings', '8:50 am - 9:30 am'], ['Grade', 'IX A'], ['Attendance', '20/26'], ['Session timings', '9:40 am - 10:20 am'], ['Grade', 'IX B'], ['Attendance', '21/25'], ['Session timings', '10:50 am - 11:30 am']]

output = {}
for item in data:
    if item[0] == 'Grade':
        grade = item[0]+'-'+item[1]
        output[grade] = {}
    else:
        output[grade][item[0]] = item[1]
        
print (output)
```

Comment: Thank you @Bhagyesh Dudhediya. The code you provided is small and nice. The thing is that I want to convert the dictionary to CSV. I will try both the answers and check which works better and accept the answer. Thanks to both.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have the same key (e.g., 'Grade') repeated more than once in a dictionary... Keys must be unique.

You could do something like this instead:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in lst:
    d[k].append(v)
d = dict(d)
```

The result is:

```
{'Grade': ['V A', 'VII A', 'IX A', 'IX B'],
 'Attendance': ['16/26', '24/31', '20/26', '21/25'],
 'Session timings': ['8:00 am - 8:40 am', '8:50 am - 9:30 am', '9:40 am - 10:20 am', '10:50 am - 11:30 am']}
```

Comment: Yes this is nice. I can now add it to csv also... Thanks

Comment: Can you tell me what type of dictionary it is called? Is it dictionary of lists?